# When is the right time to close a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Let's say I have prepared a mysqli statement by doing `$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT name, id, password_hash FROM person WHERE id = ?")` and that I use this statement in a function:

```
function get_person_info($person_id) {
    global $stmt;
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $person_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();
}
```

If I don't know how many times this function will be called, when should I close `$stmt` if I want optimal performance?

More specifically: what exactly happens when closing `$stmt`? I have read the documentation at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php), but it was unclear to me whether or not I am supposed to close a statement if I plan on reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close it. It will be closed at the script's end.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly happens when closing it?